# Set Pandas DataFrame entries by boolean index to tuple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
   a          b
0  1  (1, 1, 0)
1  1  (1, 1, 0)
2  2  (1, 1, 0)
3  1  (1, 1, 0)
```

(created by `d = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,1], 'b':[(1,1,0)]*4})`).

I'd like to assign tuple values to entries indexed by boolean values, e.g.

```
d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b'] = [(0,0,1)] * 3
```

to change the values in rows 0,1,3 to `(0,0,1)`. This does not work and throws a `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`. Note that `d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b'] = [((0,0,1),)]*3` does not throw an error, but the result is

```
   a             b
0  1  ((0, 0, 1),)
1  1  ((0, 0, 1),)
2  2     (1, 1, 0)
3  1  ((0, 0, 1),)
```

How do I get the result

```
   a          b
0  1  (0, 0, 1)
1  1  (0, 0, 1)
2  2  (1, 1, 0)
3  1  (0, 0, 1)
```

using logical indexing for rows?

Comment: Why use tuples, instead of columns?

Comment: In this case it's RGB values, which could also be RGBA values. It seems more natural to store in one cell, than to pull this together dynamically from several columns, taking into account potentially missing A values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can do:

```
# set values
ixs = [0,1,3]
vals = [[(0,0,1)]*len(ixs)]

# replace values
d.loc[ixs,['b']] = vals

   a          b
0  1  (0, 0, 1)
1  1  (0, 0, 1)
2  2  (1, 1, 0)
3  1  (0, 0, 1)
```

For pandas >= 1.0, you can do:

```
d.loc[ixs, 'b'] = pd.Series(vals, index=ixs)
```

Comment: cheers. that permutation of square brackets had not occurred to me ...

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach breaks from Pandas 1.1.0

Comment: @zeeMonkeez I've updated the solution with new approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just double wrap the tuple inside list

```
d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b'] = [[(0, 0, 1)]]

Out[78]:
   a          b
0  1  (0, 0, 1)
1  1  (0, 0, 1)
2  2  (1, 1, 0)
3  1  (0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: OK, that's even better. What's the explanation for why the double lists are needed?

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach breaks from Pandas 1.1.0

Comment: @zeeMonkeez: pandas 1.1.0+ doesn't allow assign with mismatched length such as this case. A work-around is assigning using `recarray` of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to create a Series. However, the indices have to match:

```
d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b'] = pd.Series([(0,0,1)]*len(d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b']), index=d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b'].index)
```

This seems a bit cumbersome and I hope someone else posts a better solution.

(Using the naive `d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b'] = pd.Series([(0,0,1)]*len(d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b']))` produces `NaN` in the last row, because the index 3 of the data frame is not met by a matching index in the series. This: `d.loc[d['a']==1, 'b'] = pd.Series([(0,0,1)]*len(d))` also seems to work, but seems terribly inefficient especially when most conditions are false.)

Answer (score 0):

[here is a solution, you can change the values to fit with your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veDzS.png)